# How to intercept a redirection in a popup window?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a Chrome App which needs user's authorization. Say, a user wants to share a tweet to a website and click on a button. I'll firstly search for the user's access token to that website in the Chrome storage. If not available, I' ll open a window with

```
window.open(url);
```

where the url is an authorization API provided by the website. Then the user will put in login info (username / password) and be redirected to a callback concatenated by a code required for the access token.

I don't want the user to be redirected and I need that code. 
How could I intercept that redirection, fetch the code and close the window after a user has finished authorization?

Comment: Depends entirely on how the redirection happens... If you're just submitting a form, you need to bind to the forms `submit` event and perform the submission yourself, via AJAX. You can't "intercept" a redirect once the browser has left your page.

Comment: Are you talking about an oauth 2 flow? I think Chrome match patterns allow you to hook into the redirect flow - http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html

Comment: So you want to obtain the authorization code without the user’s permission? That completely defeats the point of authorization, and you can’t do that.

Comment: @minitech no, I **HAVE** the user's permission. Note that the user has put in login info (username/password) and then is redirected to the callback url and that's where I want my code to come in. Remember when you login Slideshare with your Facebook account? You put in your facebook account in a popup window.

Comment: @JohnP Yes, a OAuth2 flow but the redirect is in a popup window. Any chance to hook into it?

Comment: @meagar I find that window.location.href is blank for the popup window and there is no way to know when the user has finished authorization. Could I write a callback function to make it happen?

Comment: @manuzhang: I don’t remember that since I’ve never done it. *Nevertheless*, the point of the code is that the user has to put it into your application, previously logged in or not. You can’t do this.

Comment: @JohnP content_script is the way out! Thanks, and I've finished the first runnable version. Would you please put your solution into answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @manuzhang glad you solved your problem, answer added. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth flows (as well as other redirection control flows) are controlled using match patterns in chrome. Match patterns allow you to hook into the flow by listening to certain urls being triggered by the browser.

More about it here - http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html

Answer (score 1):

If the callback URL is under your control, could you try using some javascript with window.opener to pass the code back, then window.close() the popup?

Comment: Yes, I define the callback URL. What do you mean by "pass the code back? Would you mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: window.opener refers to the parent window that called window.open originally - you can access it and call javascript functions and whatnot. So potentially you could do something like `window.opener.codeReceived('thecode')`, and then that function would set a variable with the code and call .close() on the popup.